# How to write this main story board code for .xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (applicationIsActive) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bildirim"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
        AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [Anothervc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController "];

        [vc presentViewController:Anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
}
```

Comment: Try `vc.storyboard` instead of `Anothervc.storyboard` in `AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [Anothervc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController "];` this line

Comment: But i want to open particular view Ex:another view when i click on notification in my Xcode also i m using xib not main storyboard

Comment: R u using storyboard or xibs in ur project

Comment: @Riddhi if you are using xib, use `alloc init` or `initWithNibName:` to instantiate the view controller and then present it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify code as below if you are using XIB's

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
AnotherViewController *anothervc = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
[navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController: Anothervc animated:YES];
```

//StoryBoards..Main is the storyBoard name..!

```
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;   
AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];                                                                     
[vc presentViewController:Anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: thank you. . it help  me to solve my problem . . its work as i want for  notification  to its particular view. .    But if i open without notification  it open another view Controller. . that time i want to open my view controller not another view controller. . plz help me for that

Comment: Keep first lines of code at didFinishLaunchOptions of AppDelegate..If push notification is not fired then didFinish will load ur basic view. Else If fired it will fire didReceiveRemoteNotification method and load another view...!

Answer (score 0):

You can get object of any `storyboard` by following code.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

Now present controller with help of you storyboard object.

```
AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];

[self presentViewController:Anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the "AnotherViewController" to your MainStoryboard.
Try to get the object of MainStoryboard like below

```
UIStoryboard *sb= [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

then modify your

```
AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [Anothervc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];
```

to

```
AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController "];
```

now present it

```
[self presentViewController:Anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XIB try this,

```
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;

AnotherViewController *anothervc = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
[vc presentViewController:anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;

AnotherViewController *Anothervc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];

[self presentViewController:Anothervc animated:YES completion:nil];